# Using set-returning functions in WHERE clauses

Tags: postgresql, set-returning-functions

```
SELECT * from users where server_id=$1 and $2=ANY(json_object_keys(contacts));

ERROR:  set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE
```

`contacts` is a `json` column and I need to find rows that has `$2` in their `contacts`' keys.

Example contacts column:
`{"90144": 0, "89915": 0}`

If `$2` is `90144`, query should return every row that contain `90144` in their `contacts`' keys, like in the example. How could I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SELECT true WHERE '90144' IN ( SELECT json_object_keys('{"90144": 0, "89915": 0}'::json))` -- true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [? operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE).

```
SELECT * from users where server_id=$1 and contacts::jsonb ? $2;
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you. But I'm curious about why casting to jsonb is mandatory. Doesn't ? work with json?

Comment: No, that one only works for JSONB.  You should maybe change your column type to JSONB, as that is much faster for this type of operation--it is stored in an already-parsed form.